# USRP B200 sample rates

Tags: usrp

What are the possible sample rates for both transmit and receive on the [Ettus USRP B200 mini](https://www.ettus.com/all-products/usrp-b200mini-i-2/) ? This SDR uses the [AD9364](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad9364.html) chip.

Comment: This question should be asked on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/